# internal error during nvprof profiling

Tags: cuda

I am using the nvprof to collect some information about applications. I can run "nvprof a.out" successfully(assuming we have a CUDA program called a.out), but I can not run "nvprof --metrics all a.out", it reports that[profiling error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqLUY.png)

Also, it can not run "nvprof --metrics ipc a.out", means that as long as I want to collect some specific metrics it will report the error.

My nvcc version and CUDA version are both 9.1
Does anyone encountered the same situation?

Answer (score 2):

I am having a quite similar issue and inspired by [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/+bug/1767205) I tried running nvprof with sudo and it seems to work.